# node:title token confused with Content Profile title

Tags: 6, tokens, users

When I update a page, the yellow Drupal $messages variable reads,
"Page *Lastname, Firstame Profile* has been updated."

Also, I send emails (using Rules) each time certain content types are created. The same problem appears when I use [node:title]. It's like it's overwritten somewhere.

After hours of searching, I cannot find an answer.

Here "User Event" is a content type:

[image]

I am running the latest version of Drupal 6.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. A content profile is a node; therefore, the content of `[node:title]` is the content profile title. What value are you expecting?

Comment: User Event is a misleading content type. 
Let's say I make a new Calendar Event and call it "Web Meeting".
This would read "Calendar Event Purvis, Mike Profile has been updated."

It loses the actual title of the node and replaces it with the Content Profile's title.